# Python script is not getting executed

Tags: python-3.x

Code is not getting executed after "remove" variable in the code below. kindly let me know what was wrong.

```
known_users = ["Kumar", "Raavi", "Raj", "Rahul"]

while True:  
  print("my name is Sachin")
  name = input("What is your name?").strip().capitalize()

  if name in known_users:
    print("hello{}!" .format(name)) 
    remove = input("Would you like to be removed? (Y/N)").lower()

    if remove=="y": #this code block is not getting executed..  
      known_users.remove(name)
      print(known_users)


  else:
    print("Hmm, i dont think we have meet yet ")
    add_name=input("Would you like me to add you in the list?").lower()

    if add_name=="y":
      known_users.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am 99% sure, that your block is not getting executed just because your condition doesn't true. First of all... you ask to input `Y` or `N`, but you check `y` in lower case. Strings are case sensitive and `y` is not equal to `Y`. So you can try to check them both or do something like:

```
if remove.lower() == "y"
```

To debug your code I would add such temporary block (remove it after bugfix):

```
if remove == "y":    
  known_users.remove(name)
  print(known_users)
else:
  print(remove)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about syntax. I don't have experience with python, so I don't know the exact syntax. Did this solve your issue?

Comment: When adding .strip(), it works but I don't know the logic of adding strip there

Comment: Can you provide me several things: 1. screenshot of the console program result, that you get after answering `Y`. 2. What is `len(remove)` value after you input the answer?

Comment: @KumarKatariya Does that helped you? Haven't got any feedback from your side

Comment: @AntonTkachor sorry it did not help but I figured that out already. Thanks for the help

Comment: @KumarKatariya Then it would be very good if you upvote my answer (at least I've tried my best to help you and spend my time) and share your own answer for future searches of other users